# Rasa NLU core.py Nonetype issue

Tags: python, nonetype, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

While running Rasa (a simple model I wrote to recognise when someone tells me his name, and stores the name in a database), I encounter an exception thrown from Rasa's core.py every time I run it:

```
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
Your input ->  My name is Michael
Exception occurred in one of response middleware handlers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 958, in handle_request
    request, response
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spf/framework.py", line 579, in _run_response_middleware
    _response = await _response
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic_cors/extension.py", line 267, in unapplied_cors_response_middleware
    set_cors_headers(req, resp, context, res_options)
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic_cors/core.py", line 254, in set_cors_headers
    headers_to_set = get_cors_headers(options, req.headers, req.method)
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic_cors/core.py", line 174, in get_cors_headers
    origins_to_set = get_cors_origins(options, request_headers.get('Origin'))
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic_cors/core.py", line 149, in get_cors_origins
    return sorted([o for o in origins if not probably_regex(o)])
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic_cors/core.py", line 149, in <listcomp>
    return sorted([o for o in origins if not probably_regex(o)])
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic_cors/core.py", line 273, in probably_regex
    return any((c in maybe_regex for c in common_regex_chars))
  File "/Users/Kami/Documents/rasa/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic_cors/core.py", line 273, in <genexpr>
    return any((c in maybe_regex for c in common_regex_chars))
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I have tried running in debug, but no message there seems to pertain to this problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: There is already an issue for it on GitHub here - https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/4545.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a Rasa bug in v1.3.7 (and v1.3.8).
It can be solved in two ways that I have found:

1. Downgrade to v1.3.3: `pip uninstall rasa; pip install rasa==1.3.3` 
   run
2. Run rasa with the argument `cors '*'`